# Why is *salāta feminine? What was the original noun it is modifying?

Tags: etymology, medieval-latin, vulgar-latin, romance-languages

OED traces the "salad" family of words (Portuguese *salada*, Fra. *salate*, Spa. *ensalada*, Ita. *insalata* etc.) to spoken Latin **salāta*, from the verb *salāre*.

One notices that *salāta* as well as all its descendants are feminine.  My question is, what is the feminine noun that the participle is implied to be modifying? It is a salted *what*?

Comment: btw, in German "Salat" is masculine.

Comment: It sounds a prime candidate for a neuter plural being reinterpreted as a feminine singular.

Comment: Stipulation: Because it's elided from a compound, *plantname salata*, *salted leaves of plant so and so*. The partucular plant (brasica?) doesn't matter much at this point, plants are simply feminine, often enough.

Comment: @MartinKochanski That's a very good guess! Can you post it as an answer? We might not have a fully definitive answer, but explaining that and maybe giving other examples would be great.

Comment: The etymological dictionaries usually trace it to Italian *insalata*, cf.  "Empr. à l'ital. du Nord salada, salata, ital. insalata (att. au sens 1 dep. fin xiiie-déb. xives., Cenne de La Chitarra; dér. insalatuzza ds Boccace, Décaméron ds Batt.), part. passé de salare, insalare « saler », du lat. tardif salare, insalare « id. », dér. de sal, -is (sel*). Voir FEW t. 11, p. 82b et 84a, et Hope, pp. 49-50." https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/salade

Comment: btw, one of the first attestations of *insalata* (a feminine noun in Italian) is Domenico Cavalca (c. 1270-1342): "fece un'insalata di erbe, e con poco d'aceto e oglio cenarono." (Grande dizionario della lingua italiana) http://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/8?seq=85 cf. Zingarelli 2021, "av. 1342"

Answer (score 3):

It could easily originally be a neuter plural: *salata* — "salted things".